# Webpage Layout Issue

Tags: html, css, tablelayout

I am having a problem with the layout of my webpage. I have 2 tables and those 2 tables both inside 2 divs. The problem I'm having is that when my web browser is resized  the content in the second div moves below the first div.

Can anyone please tell me how this can be fixed?

Comment: Please post your CSS and HTML part which contains your problem

Comment: Are you floating these divs to make them next to each other?

Comment: Adding a `min-width` to your `body` tag that is at LEAST the width of both divs is a possible solution, however without your code, it's hard to understand your situation completely.

Comment: using center tag it may be help to you

Answer (score 1):

One way to fix this is to put a table outside of the divs.  If the tables are inside of a structure div, resizing the browser will not force one div to move down.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
CSS
#leftcolumn { width: 300px; border: 1px solid red; float: left}
#rightcolumn { width: 300px; border: 1px solid red; float: right}

HTML
<div id="leftcolumn"><p>text goes here</p></div>
<div id="rightcolumn"><p>text goes here</p></div>
```

Also if you use float it affectivly removes that element from any surrounding div. To get around this problem try and add a div class which has 'clear' set to 'both' to your html. This make all the divs sit nicely in there container

Like this:

```
CSS
.clear { clear: both;}

HTML
<div id"container">
  <div id="leftcolumn"><p>text goes here</p></div>
  <div id="rightcolumn"><p>text goes here</p></div>
  <div class"clear"></div>
</div>
```